# is there any difference between `git reset HEAD` and `git reset HEAD~`

Tags: git, commit, reset

I'm currently learning the git `reset` command.

I was just wondering, what is the difference between `git reset HEAD` vs `git reset HEAD~`.

Are these commands two ways to achieve the same thing? Or there are difference between them that are only observable under certain conditions?

when I run these two commands on the under the same circumstances, they seem to behave the same, but in order to avoid the `what you see is all there is` pitfall, I'm asking the question just to be sure.

Comment: `HEAD~` is the first parent of `HEAD`. Make sure you have at least two commits in the repo and you'll see the changes.

Comment: hi @axiac, thank you for the comment. So judging from what you said, I guess both `git reset HEAD` and `git reset HEAD~` means the same i.e. they both mean: make `HEAD` pointer points to the parent commit of the commit the `HEAD` is currently pointed to? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. `HEAD~` is not the same commit as `HEAD`.

Comment: oh, my bad. I understand that `HEAD~` means the parent commit of the commit where `HEAD` pointer is currently pointing to. `HEAD` is just a pointer that tells you where you are at present. But when I use both `HEAD~` and `HEAD` in the context of `git reset`, they both move the `HEAD` pointer to point to the parent commit. Both `HEAD~` and `HEAD` seem to have the same effect when used with `git reset` :( I'm confused

Comment: What version of Git are you using? I just checked both commands and they surely leave the repo in different states.

Comment: Read about the ways to specify [Git revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions).

Comment: @axiac sorry, my bad. I dont know what I was thinking or doing just then, but I tried again and they do indeed have different effects. Thank you so much for pointing it out!

Comment: Remember, `HEAD` means *current commit*. If something, such as `git reset HEAD~`, *changes* which commit is *current*, the meaning of `HEAD` has just changed as well. So it matters whether you do `git reset HEAD; git reset HEAD~` vs `git reset HEAD~; git reset HEAD~`. But if you do `git reset HEAD~` (changes HEAD) and then `git reset HEAD` (uses changed HEAD but doesn't change it again), or `git reset HEAD` (uses unchanged HEAD) and then `git reset HEAD~` (changes HEAD), you have only changed once, either way.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same if you only have one commit otherwise `HEAD~` will always refer to the first parent of the commit.

In addition I can suggest some interesting reading for `git reset`.

`git reset HEAD` unrolls to `git reset --mixed HEAD`. From the documentation for `--mixed`

So `git reset HEAD~` will unroll to `git reset --mixed HEAD~1` which means `Reset the HEAD's first parent with the --mixed option`

> --mixed
>   Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

I now refer to the very good blog entry [git reset demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog). 
*Side Note*: From this blog post I finally learned how reset is actually working.

> Now take another second to look at THAT diagram and realize what it did. It still undid your last commit, but also unstaged everything. You rolled back to before you ran all your git adds AND git commit.

Comment: `HEAD^1` is not the same as `HEAD`.

Comment: Yes I realized it after I tried something, I updated my introduction. Are you ok with it or any other hints?

Comment: hi ckruczek, thanks for the links! I had a glance through, and they seem to be really good.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, `git reset COMMIT` (equivalent of `git reset --mixed COMMIT`) means:

1. Move the `HEAD` reference to points to `COMMIT`
2. Reset the index to the tree of `COMMIT`

(`git reset` is fully explained in [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified))

On the other hand:

- `HEAD` represents the current commit
- `HEAD~` represents the first ancestor of `HEAD`

(The meaning of `~` is explained in the documentation of [git revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions), look at the example at the end of the section for better understanding)

When you combine both:

- `git reset HEAD`: simply reset the index
- `git reset HEAD~`: move to previous commit and reset index accordingly

In both cases your working directory will never be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

running

```
git reset HEAD~
git reset HEAD
```

the second command has no effect because after the first the new HEAD is previous HEAD~.
see

```
git rev-parse HEAD HEAD~ HEAD^@
```

Note that `git reset HEAD~` can be undone with

```
git reset HEAD@{n}
```

where n can be retrieved with `git reflog`